# Create Magento customer directly to Magento database

Tags: php, database, magento, yii

What i need is a solution to create a magento customer from an external php application (developed in the yii framework) connected directly to a magento database. The customer info will be entered using a form. The only fields from the magento customer that i am really interested in are customer email and password i.e. i want to create a customer with minimum field that only include email and password as form entry. However, i do not mind adding first name and last name to the form if they are "required" fields. I know that for Magento customer creation, webstore_id and store_id are required, but these can be hard-coded to default values thats okay.

I found code online that demonstrate how to create a customer while utilizing the Mage.php file. Some links to these tutorials include:
http://www.douglasradburn.co.uk/adding-new-customers-to-the-magento-store-programmatically/
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programming-magento/programmaticaly-adding-new-customers-to-the-magento-store/

But in these tutorials, they have hard-coded the customer info. Like i said, my requirements include using forms on a php page from an external php application in yii framework.

Solutions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should check customer soap api in magento

Answer (score 0):

Create a module in your magento for retrieving the informations from your script and then implement this kind of stuff : 
[Create customer programmatically](http://www.douglasradburn.co.uk/adding-new-customers-to-the-magento-store-programmatically/)